# List of Predefined Activities

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am currently exploring forge design automation API's for extracting some text information from the 2D drawing file(DWG). In one of the example code provided in the Forge API samples, it is mentioned that 'PlotToPDF' as a predefined activity. Is there a list of predefined activities documented somewhere that can be used with the design automation API's? I could not find anything related this in the Forge API documentation portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PlotToPdf is the only documented predefined activity at this time. You can get all activities that you have access to by GET /activities.